# React layout help - Can't get my SVG's to be a set size while also responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

I am trying to develop a website using Gatsby and React (however, this question is about React).

I am new to web development so I am trying to figure out some of the basics.

My issue is with the landing page. I made two SVG's I would like to be a part of the landing page (Text and a Logo) but I can't size them correctly while also making them responsive.

Image of what I want the page to look like

[image: Image of what I want the page to look like]

The reason I am using SVG's is because I wrote a little JS piece that animates the hero when you open the page.

I read lots of Stack Overflow questions on making SVGs responsive using the `viewBox` attribute but I can't figure out how to set the size of the two SVGs without removing its responsive qualities. So, the page just has two huge SVGs spanning the whole viewport. Even when I try and specify the width on the SVGs, they get clipped on smaller screens instead of scaling down.

An issue I noticed is that if I embed the two SVGs in a `div`, if I go to inspect that `div` then it has a height of 0 and is in the top left corner and the SVGs are way out in the middle of the page, as they do.

I am using Bootstrap 4 and have a little Navbar at the top that everything seems to be ignoring (as in, my `div` seems to go behind the Navbar all willy-nilly).

The following is the code structure I am using to render this (through React components):

```
 <div> 
  <Hero>
   <HeroTitle>
     <svg1>
     <svg2>
   <HeroTitle/>
  </Hero>
 </div>
```

CSS for SVGs:

```
#svg-hero-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}

#svg1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#svg2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 742 58"  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
...
</svg>

<svg id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 672 210" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
...
</svg>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is a live site of where I'm at: https://emmarose.netlify.com/

Here is the GitHub repo in case my code isn't sufficient: https://github.com/eduardoRubioG/emrose-cslate

Answer (score 0):

Specify width for each svg tags.

```
<svg1 id="svg1">
<svg2 id="svg2">

#svg1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#svg2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: I tried this -- and it definitely sizes the SVGs down to a size I like. However, they become unresponsive and the SVGs no longer scale up or down as I change the screen size or open the site on different sizes. I would like to set the initial size of the SVGs and then maintain that responsive quality! Thoughts?